# jQuery RegEx in If-statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following list

```
<li class='lists'>Sonata</li>
<li class='lists'>http://facebook.com</li>
<li class='lists'>Omega</li>
<li class='lists'>Rule of Thumb</li>
<li class='lists'>https://youtube.com</li>
```

I want to wrap only the text that contains `http://` or `https://` with the URL link. So, what I am doing currently in jQuery is:

```
if ($('li.lists:contains(http://)') || ('li.lists:contains(https://)')) {
    $('li.lists:contains(http://)').wrapInner(function () {
        return "<a href='" + $(this).text() + "'></a>";
    });

    $('li.lists:contains(https://)').wrapInner(function () {
        return "<a href='" + $(this).text() + "'></a>";
    });
}
```

As you can see, just for one character `s` in link, I have to use `or ||` statement and call the `wrapInner()` function twice.

Is it possible to acheive this with Regular Expression in jQuery with one liners like

```
if ($('li.lists:contains(http/?s/://)')) {
```

OR

```
$('li.lists:contains(http/?s/://)')
```

something like this.

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vQBN/2/)** for the above codes.

Comment: You could do a `.test()` on the text in the `li`. Eg. `regEx.test(listItem1.text())`. `test()` returns a boolean if the argument passed in passes the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/U9shT/1)</kbd>

```
$('li.lists').html(function (_, html) {
    return html.replace(/((?:http|https):\/\/.+)$/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
});
```

---

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/U9shT/)</kbd>

```
var urlPattern = new RegExp("(http|https)://");
$('li.lists').filter(function (_, str) {
    return urlPattern.test(str.innerHTML);
}).wrapInner(function () {
    return "<a href='" + $(this).text() + "'></a>";
});
```

Comment: I am looking for api documentation for `.test()` couldn't find any. May be you know it better, does this work in IE8?

Comment: @JhilkeDai Read [.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)